# Javassist how to debug modified java method

Tags: eclipse, debugging, bytecode, javassist, cglib

use Javassist to add some code statically at the beginning of a method right after the class is compiled. For example,

```
public String getFoo() {
    // add some code here

    return "foo";
}
```

From Eclipse debug, I can not see the added code. Is there a way for Eclipse to show de-compiled code instead of original source?

How to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the CtClass, you can call CtClass.writeFile to save the bytecode of the resulting java class. Then you can use a java decompiler to view the source. The generated source is not perfect ( it would probably not compile ) but it gives you a good idea of what's going on. I use the decompiler built into IntelliJ ( community edition ) but some googling will find you a few other options.